# How to extract only a part of a string

Tags: regex, grep

I have a batch file using wget and grep that downloads a website, and then extracts the fallowing string from the source code.

```
<p>11.59 €</p>
```

As you can see, grep included the paragraph tags, which I want to exclude.
How would that be done?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a regex expression, perhaps something like this: `/<[^>]*>/g`

The expression should exclude the tags you mentioned as well as things such as

etc.

Comment: You cannot parse [x]html using regular expressions. [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) ;)

Comment: LMFAO, the way that post ends is beautiful :) Would that expression not work with his example lines where I imagine it will only be <p> </p> etc? I'll update my phrasing :)

Comment: http://www.regexpal.com/ suggests it would be OK for the OP's simple case ;)